# Angular dynamic templates with innerHTML convert the method to string

Tags: javascript, angular, templates, dynamic, innerhtml

I try to load html with innerHTML but it does not work.

page.ts

```
htmlStr = `<div [ngClass]="getClass('COLECTOR')">HELLO WORLD</div>`;
```

page.html

```html
<div [class]="getClass('COLECTOR')"> </div>
```

When I inspect code in Chrome:

-If i use [innerHtml] the method doesn't work. See the method as  string:

```html
<div [ngclass]="getClass('COLECTOR')">HELLO WORLD</div>
```

-If I don't use the pipe i only see:

```html
<div>HELLO WORLD</div>
```

But.............

If i put the div tag in the page.thml without load the html from the string with innerHTML it works

```html
<div [ngClass]="getClass('COLECTOR')">HELLO WORLD</div>
```

when inspect the code i see:

```html
<div class="manual">HELLO WORLD</div>
```

This last is what i want to get but loading the HTML from a string.

pipe

```
@Pipe({
  name: "domSanitizer",
})
export class DomSanitizerPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(value: string, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
        switch (type) {
            case 'html':
                return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
...
```

Comment: You can only load basic HTML with `innerHTML` anything that is angular related like `ngClass` will not work inside `innerHTML`

Comment: Why are you using `innerHTML` when it is almost always an anti-pattern in Angular?

Comment: And how would you use a dynamic template? I bring the html from a database. 
How do you recommend me to do it?